# Given three integers A,B,C, how to find number of positive integral solutions of $a*b>c^2$ with a,b,c having upper bounds A,B,C resp.

Tags: optimization, algorithms, contest-math

A and B can be as large as $10^9$. However, $C$ is given to be within 5k types.

I tried writing a code, but it's in $O(A*C)$ and it's taking a huge time when $A, C$ exceeds say $5k$.

Comment: What does "However C is given to be within 5k types" mean?  What have you done so far?

Comment: C is within 5k means that the constraints are defined like this: 1<=A,B <=1e9 , 1<=C<=5,000.

I have done a somewhat optimized brute force, for every positive integral a * b within A * B, I just keep adding min(sqrt(a * b),C). If a * b is a perfect square itself, then take min(sqrt(a*b)-1,C).

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  It sounds like it comes from a programming contest.

Comment: It's a recreational maths problem given by a friend of mine I'm trying to solve. More of a maths olympiad type. I don't know  if it's from any contest or not.